# Best Layout for Dynamically Sized Panel

Tags: java, swing, layout

What I am looking for is a suggestion for the best layout to use for my scenario.  I basically have any number of child panels which can be in a container panel that can be dynamically resized by the user.  All of the child panels will be 300 pixels in width, and can have a variable height.  I would like the panels to be placed into the panel from left-to-right, top-to-bottom, just like the `FlowLayout`.  However, anything I try with the `FlowLayout` will vertically center the panel with less height.  I would instead like the panel to be anchored to the top of the screen.

I have created the following example using the `FlowLayout` to show what I mean.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DynamicPanel extends JPanel {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.add(new DynamicPanel());
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public DynamicPanel() {
        setupGUI();
    }

    private void setupGUI() {
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        this.add(getPanel(1, 4));
        this.add(getPanel(2, 2));
    }

    private JPanel getPanel(int panelNum, int numButtons) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout()) {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                Dimension ret = super.getPreferredSize();
                ret.width = 300;
                return ret;
            }
        };
        panel.add(new JLabel("Panel "+panelNum), getGrid(0, 0, 1.0, 0));
        for(int i = 0; i < numButtons; i++) {
            panel.add(new JButton("Button"), getGrid(0, i+1, 1.0, 0));
        }
        return panel;
    }

    /*
     * Returns the GridBagConstraints for the given x, y grid location
     */
    private GridBagConstraints getGrid(int x, int y, double xweight, double yweight) {
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        c.gridx = x;
        c.gridy = y;
        c.weightx = xweight;
        c.weighty = yweight;

        return c;
    }
}
```

In this example, I would like the labels Panel1, and Panel2 to be straight across from each other, instead of Panel2 being set lower because the associated panel is centered.

I guess I could use GridBagLayout, and add a component listener to the container panel, and edit the `GridBagContraints` accordingly for each child panel when the container panel is resized, but I am wondering if there is a better way to do this?  In case this matters, in the actual program the child panels will be custom panels, not just a list of buttons.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve this

[image: Columns]

Using this...

```
private void setupGUI() {
    this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
    gbc.weighty = 1;
    this.add(getPanel(1, 4), gbc);
    this.add(getPanel(2, 2), gbc);
}
```

The problem is, you're going to need to get your hands a little dirty, as no layout manager will do exactly what you want (with the possible exception of MigLayout, but I've never used it)

What I would do, is create a `JPanel` per row, set it's layout to `GridBagLayout` and use the above concept to layout to layout the number of columns you need, then do this for each row...

Comment: Okay, so if initially 6 columns are present, and the user resizes the window so that only 5 columns will fit, is it better to call `gridBagLayout.setConstraints(panel, newConstraints)` or to do `gridBagLayoutPanel.remove(panel)` and then `gridBagLayoutPanel.add(panel, newConstraints)`, or does it not really matter?

Comment: Depending on how you've laid it out (I'd probably lay it all out in a single container using `GridBagLayout` as apposed to using a separate panel for each row), you can use `setConstraints` - I think it would be simpler, but you'd need to play around with it ;)